# Creating Table using Local CSV File

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following query to create a table however the file name is located on my local machine (as I don't have access to the Oracle Box) how can I use a local file to create a table on the Oracle Database). All the examples I have seen assume the file is located on the Oracle Database Server.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY file_dir AS 'c:/temp';
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY file_dir TO CPS_OWNER;

create table CPS_OWNER.TEMP_TOGGLE_LIST (
      USER_ID varchar2(30)   
    )
    organization external (
      type oracle_loader
      default directory file_dir
      access parameters (records delimited by newline fields)
     location ('users.csv')
  )
  reject limit unlimited;
```

Comment: You can't create an external table if the data file is not available to the database server's file system.  You can create a normal heap-organized table and load it by running `SQL*Loader` on the client machine (assuming `SQL*Loader` is installed on the client machine) or you can use the SQL Developer import utility.  SQL Developer is probably easier for a one-time load, `SQL*Loader` is probably preferred if you want to script it out.

Answer (score 16):

Right click in SQL Developer on the Tables node in the connection tree.

[image: Where to click]

Select 'Import Data'

Point to your CSV file.

Go through the wizard.

I talk about this in detail with screenshots [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/how-to-import-from-excel-to-a-new-oracle-table-with-sql-developer/).

Or, [watch the Movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3R8I27dgvy4).

Comment: can't be easier than that!

Comment: is that "imported" to the database on the server, or is it only in "temporary" memory for a given query? (I'm new to this and am unfamiliar with the correct terminologies/concepts)

Comment: the rows are inserted into the table...once a COMMIT happens, the data is available for EVERYONE to see, before the COMMIT, only you will see the data in your session.